# Concurrent modification of an object's attributes

Tags: java, multithreading

For example: There are 3 threads that modify an instance of `Demo`: Thread `A` modifies `demo.a` , thread `B` modifies `demo.b` and thread `C` modifies `demo.c`. Is this ok? Will these modifications cause a problem in regard of multithreading? Why?

Here's the class for illustration:

```java
class Demo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It depends on what changes are supposed to be visible for each thread. Could you give more details?

Comment: i just want to get the final result of the instance of Demo, there are no need fo each thread to know other.  i wonder to know, will instance be covered? i want demo.a = a,demo.b=b,demo.c=c; but  in multithread enviroment, is it possible to make demo.a = a,demo.b=null,demo.c=null?

Comment: Yes, you can. But the question is; Will every thread see those changes and does it need to? When thread `A` sets `demo.a = a` then this will be garanteed to be visible for `A`. But there won't be a garantee that the other threads see the new value for `demo.a`. If you want other threads to see the change, you need to apply correct synchronization.

Comment: Thanks.In my case, each thread only need to handle one attribute fo Demo. Actually, i am very confused. Because, in my view, thread A will has a local cache, and it will cache demo, when thread A sets demo.a = a, but demo.b now is null, so when thread A flush local cache to main memory, will demo in main memory be covered?  If it covered, the result will be wrong.